# are there any advantages to having a short TTL?

Tags: dns, cache, dns-servers

I'm currently doing a study on the DNS and I was wondering whether there are any advantages to setting a short TTL on a DNS record stored in a local cache.

Comment: Yes, DNS changes happen more quickly, but not all DNS servers respect the TTL... many override and set their own.

Comment: One warning: Making the number too low increases the load on the DNS. As well, at one point, Google did look at TTL times as an indication of spammer activity. Of course this was one of very many factors and extremely likely not a factor today. My point being that TTL times are used form more than DNS just like registration information. I have to admit, my TTL times are too low - I just keep forgetting to up them from the ridiculous default of 3600.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by Simon in a comment above:

> Yes, DNS changes happen more quickly, but not all DNS servers respect the TTL... many override and set their own